# Using Apache Spark's Time class/type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Note: I am using Spark 2.2.0. I am getting an error when trying to run my Scala code from my Zeppelin notebook

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Time, Seconds, StreamingContext}
...
...
case class Record(time: Time, topic: String, count: Integer)
...
...
```

`import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Time, Seconds, StreamingContext}` should allow me to use `Time`

When I try to run the paragraph/block in Zeppelin, I am getting this error:
`<console>:12: error: not found: type Time`
`case class Record(time: Time, topic: String, count: Integer)`

What could the issue be? Is `Time` deprecated or something in Spark 2? Any alternative to `Time`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using Spark SQL or Spark Structured Streaming, I can recommend sticking to `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date`: they are fully integrated with the ecosystems, meaning you won't need custom serializers and there are [very nice built-in functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@add_months(startDate:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,numMonths:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (look them up in the `Date functions` section) that you can use.